# C# : incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm creating a login window in c# with SQL server following this guys tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NX8-LhgFnUU

I did everything like he did but I get an error in my code when I debug the app and type username and password and click login. It brings me to code which is this code / screenshots:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYSSj.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qjI9.png

Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\eAlati - 1366x768\FastFoodDemo\DB\logindb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    string query = "Select * from Table Where username = '" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "'and password = '" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'";

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dtbl);

    if(dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        ucitavanje objUcitavanje = new ucitavanje();
        this.Hide();
        objUcitavanje.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Vaše korisničko ime ili lozinka nisu točni! Pokušajte ponovno");
    }
}
```

Thanks for understanding :)

Comment: Table is a reserved keyword in Sql Server (or practically in any database system) use square brackets around that name. _[Table]_ But after this simple error, I suggest you to read how to write parameterized queries.

Comment: I would caution against a table named :"Table", use something more descriptive such as LoginUsers or some such.  Also you open yourself up to SQL injection attacks with that SQL built from a string, use parameters there.

Comment: Thank you very much Steve, it works now :)

Comment: Going along with the above comments: the name `table` is also a horrible name for a table. How often do you see files on disk called `file` or directories named `directory` or users named `user`? All poor choices. Use a descriptive name  based on what you will be storing in the table.

Comment: Again look at this QA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: @Steve, too funny, forgot about that one on here :)

Comment: You also appear to be storing a password in plaintext in your database. That's a big security violation. Passwords should be one way hashed and salted, never stored in plaintext.

Comment: @mason it's for school competition so security violation doesn't matter, but thanks for the info :)

Comment: You have to love University of YouTube "courses".  The absolute minimum to get something limping along and none of the stuff you *need* to know

Comment: Even in school you should get in the habit of doing it the right way. Use parameterized queries. Even better would be to use stored procedures and don't put your query in the application at all. Since this is school it would be a great time to learn how to salt and hash passwords correctly. Either your professor would be thrilled that you did it or they are so clueless they wouldn't understand what you did.

Answer (score 1):

For the fix I put Table in square brackets like this [Table]
this solved things :D

Comment: The **much better** fix would be to use **more meaningful** names for your own database objects, and refrain from using such overly generic terms like `table`, `object`, `column` etc. ....